sed: To match a newline and spaces
I have a following file:
<head>
  <title>this is a title</title>
  <style>
    here goes a style sheet
  </style>
</head>

I need to strip the <title> element from it, with sed. Currently I use
cat test.html | sed 's/<title>.*<\/title>//'

and it works, but I don't understand how to get rid of the blank line. That is, currently the output is
<head>
  
  <style>
    here goes a style sheet
  </style>
</head>

Whereas I want it to be
<head>
  <style>
    here goes a style sheet
  </style>
</head>

For this, I tried to add \s* or \n*, using both GNU and BSD sed,
cat test.html | sed 's/<title>.*<\/title>\s*//'

cat test.html | sed 's/<title>.*<\/title>\n*//'

but this didn't help. What I'm doing wrong?
Edit: The <title> line doesn't have to be on a separate line. That is, sometime the whole file can be just a single line:
<head><title>this is a title</title><style>here goes a style sheet</style></head>

In such a case, the desired output is
<head><style>here goes a style sheet</style></head>


If you don't have and can't install XML-aware tools then using any awk (a mandatory POSIX tool, present on all Unix boxes) and only reading 1 line at a time into memory, assuming your title string is always on a single line and neither <title> nor </title> show up in other contexts on that line and don't appear together in other contexts on other lines, all you need is:
awk 'sub("<title>.*</title>","") && !NF{next} 1'

The above just says "remove the title string (sub("<title>.*</title>","")) and if the resulting line is empty (!NF) then don't print it (next)".
To demonstrate, using this input file created from examples in the OPs question and answer:
$ cat file
<head><title>this is a title</title><style>here goes a style sheet</style></head>

<head>
  <!-- beware of <title>! -->
  <title>this is a title</title>
    <style>
      p { color: red; }
    </style>
  <!-- beware of </title>! -->
</head>

we can see the title strings being removed without blank lines being left behind and without the subsequent <style> line's indent changing:
$ awk 'sub("<title>.*</title>","") && !NF{next} 1' file
<head><style>here goes a style sheet</style></head>

<head>
  <!-- beware of <title>! -->
    <style>
      p { color: red; }
    </style>
  <!-- beware of </title>! -->
</head>

Regarding:

I tried to add \s* or \n*, using both GNU and BSD sed,
cat test.html | sed 's/<title>.*<\/title>\s*//'
at test.html | sed 's/<title>.*<\/title>\n*//'
but this didn't help. What I'm doing wrong?

In the first script you're using \s which is a non-POSIX GNU extension to sed as shorthand for [[:space:]] and in both scripts you're trying to match a newline but sed reads each line of input 1 line at a time into it's buffer for operating on so there is no newline in the buffer for sed to match your regexp against. There are various ways to handle that in sed (GNU sed for -z to read the whole file into memory at once, or some sed instruction to append lines to a "hold space", or a compound block of actions based on the result of the subsitution) but it's clearer, simpler, more efficient, and more portable to just use awk.

The s command in sed modifies lines.  To delete lines, use the d command.  Assuming the title node, including its value, is on a single line in the input document, you could do that with
sed '\,<title>.*</title>,d' file

(using , as an alternate delimiter for the address to delete.)
It would be quicker (less thinking) to use grep -v though:
grep -v '<title>.*</title>' file

However, since this is an XML file, I would use a tool that understands this structured document format.  The below uses xmlstarlet and would not care if the title node's value contained newlines or if the node itself contained attributes. It would only delete the title node beneath the top-level head node and nothing else, whereas sed and grep, not knowing about the document's structure, would blindly delete any line that matches the pattern you give it.
$ xmlstarlet edit --delete '/head/title' file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<head>
  <style>
    here goes a style sheet
  </style>
</head>

If adding the XML declaration is unwanted, use xmlstarlet with its -O (or --omit-decl) option.  You can also do "in-place" editing with -L (or --inplace).
With these options in effect, and using shortened syntax:
$ xmlstarlet ed -O -L -d '/head/title' file
$ cat file
<head>
  <style>
    here goes a style sheet
  </style>
</head>

If the document is an HTML document (not XHTML, which is already XML), you can use xmlstarlet to convert it into XML before editing it, using
xmlstarlet format --html file

E.g.
$ xmlstarlet format --html file | xmlstarlet edit --delete '/html/head/title'
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <style><![CDATA[
    here goes a style sheet
  ]]></style>
  </head>
</html>

Note that we need to use the path /html/head/title rather than the shorter /head/title, because the head node must be contained in a html node for it to be a valid XHTML file (if it was an XML file from the start, we could obviously skip this step entirely).

I use macOS. Out if curiosity, is xmlstarlet supplied with mainstream Linux distros or instead should be installed by the user?

@jsx97 I'm not really a Linux user, but xmlstarlet is available for all the distribution I've come across. I'm also using it on macOS (via Homebrew) as well as on OpenBSD and FreeBSD.

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -ne 'put $_ unless / "<title>" .* "</title>" /;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -ne '  .put unless / "<title>" .* "</title>" /;'  file

The Raku code above will skip the <title> element without producing a blank line. Two ways of returning linewise text are shown. The first uses put $_ ($_ is Raku/Perl's topic variable loaded with a line of text). The second uses .put (which is short for $_.put).
Sample Output (from OP's example file):
<head>
  <style>
    here goes a style sheet
  </style>
</head>


Using Raku with the XML module:
~$  raku -MXML -e 'my $xml = open-xml("/path/to/file"); my $nodes = $xml.nodes; 
                   my $index = $nodes.first( /\<title\>/, :k); 
                   $xml.removeChild($nodes[$index]); $xml.removeChild($nodes[$index-1]); 
                   put $xml;'    file

Above Raku code that calls Raku's XML module at the command line accomplishes the same task. The file is read into an XML::Document named $xml. The file is decomposed into nodes. The node containing the first occurrence of \<title\> is identified and its :k key-position  stored as $index an index value. Then that child node is removed using the removeChild() method. To avoid leaving a blank line in the file the $index-1 position must be removed as well. Finally, the resultant file is output.
Sample Output (note automatic addition of XML header):
<?xml version="1.0"?><head>
  <style>
    here goes a style sheet
  </style>
</head>

https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML
https://raku.org
